# On linux, how do I prevent the creation of .DS_Store files?

Tags: linux

```
defaults write com.apple.desktopservices DSDontWriteNetworkStores true
```

works on Mac but not Linux. This problem is caused by my use of SSHFS.

Answer (score 0):

I am not really familiar with OS X, but it sounds as if your OS X client considers your SSHFS mount to be a local volume and thus the Finder creates cache files on your remote Linux server.

[As far as I can tell](https://github.com/osxfuse/osxfuse/wiki/FAQ) OSXFUSE filesystems are considered non-local by default. So, first of all, you should make sure that you are not mounting the SSHFS filesystem with the `-o local` option.

If that was not the problem, then you may need to use the `noappledouble` mount option for FUSE, which will apparently prevent the creation of some Apple-specific files on the remote server, such as those created by the Finder. I am unaware if using that option has any unwanted side-effects, though.